# Get focus on a textbox inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, gridview, textbox

I have created a WPF page with a `GridView`. In that `GridView` there are 5 `TextBox`es available per row. When I enter the data on the first `TextBox` in the first row and then press tab, the focus moves onto the next `TextBox`. I enter the data on that `TextBox` and press tab and so on.... 
Finally I enter the data on the last `TextBox` on that row and press the enter key. The focus moves to elements outside the `GridView`.

I want the focus to move onto the first `TextBox` of the second row of the `GridView`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this on the text box you want to focus..

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```